# Subquery with a clause "Exists", where information need to be gathered from two tables

Tags: sql, subquery, exists

So, there are two tables. One where all the information about product is listed (ID, ProductName, SupplierID, UnitPrice, Package, IsDiscontinued) and the other one where the information about supplier is stored (ID, CompanyName, ContactName, City, Country,...)
I need to find suppliers with products over 100$. So the code given is as follows:

```
SELECT CompanyName
FROM Supplier
WHERE EXISTS
( SELECT ProductName
FROM Product 
WHERE supplierID = supplier.ID
AND unitprice > 100);
```

I don't understand why on subquery we need to SELECT ProductName not any other field from the table Product? Also when the system has detected all the product names with unitprice > 100 and matching supplierID with the other table, from where do it gather what's the company's name?

Comment: What's your dbms? could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: *I don't understand why on subquery we need to SELECT ProductName not any other field* you can select any other column, even all columns, even a constant like `select 1...` or even null: `select null...`.

Comment: `SELECT 1` or `SELECT NULL` will do too.

Comment: SELECT 1/0 works just fine as well.

Comment: In Postgres you can even remove the column list completely , where exists `(select from product ...)` works as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why on subquery we need to SELECT ProductName not
>   any other field

You can select any other column, even all columns, even a constant like `select 1...` or even `null`: `select null...`.

The purpose of using this subquery is to make sure that there `EXISTS` at least a row having the properties provided in its `WHERE` clause.

> when the system has detected all the product names with unitprice >
>   100 and matching supplierID with the other table, from where do it
>   gather what's the company's name?

The statement is:

```
SELECT CompanyName
FROM Supplier
................
```

so the company's name is of course *gathered* from the table `Supplier` if and only if a row `EXISTS` in the table `Product` with `supplierID` equal to the `ID` of the row from table `Suppliers` with the additional condition of having `unitprice > 100`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `exists` only cares whether rows are returned not the value in the row.  So, it makes no difference what columns are selected.  I usually just use `1`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Product
              WHERE supplierID = supplier.ID AND unitprice > 100
             )
```

`1` is easy to type.

Comment: I usually use `*` ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . That requires a shift key on my keyboard.